# Foundation 3 - Orbit Slider custom navigation using button rows

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit

As per Foundation 4 it is possible to switch slides using a button outside the orbit slider. Is this possible in Foundation 3?

I have a button group (see below) that corresponds with individual slides within the orbit slider the goal is when button is clicked it changes slide in the slider.

```
 <ul class="button-group even three-up">
        <li><a href="#" class="button sliderbutton">Slide 1 text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="button sliderbutton">Slide 2 text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="button sliderbutton">Slide 3 text</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks a ton in advance.